# Jupyter notebook Dropdown width

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am placing a dropdown widget in a Jupyter notebook using the ipywidgets dropdown class as follows:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

ids = ['This is a very long string that is too long for the box',
      'This is another very long string that is too long as well',
      'The more, the merrier: One last long string that identifies something']

current = widgets.Dropdown(options=ids, value=ids[0],
                           description='Current dataset:', width='500px')
display(current)
```

The dropdown field itself is wide enough for the long strings but when list of options is opened, the width of this list is too small and also doesn't follow the given 'width' parameter in the declaration (see picture).

Is there a way to set the width of the option list for the dropdown menu? I would like it to be wide enough to display the whole string.

[image: Problem display]

Comment: Works for me. Try a different browser.

Comment: Thanks for trying. It's the same for me in Firefox and Safari on OSX. Which operating system were you using?

Comment: Firefox 50.0.2 on OSX. Jupyter version 4.1.0.

Comment: I just tried with Firefox ESR 45.6, Fireefox 50.0.2 and Jupyter Client 4.2.2, Jupyter Core 4.1.0 on OSX with the same result.
Same problem for me on Windows 10 with a fresh install of Anaconda and Firefox 50.
PS: Using Python 3.5. Which version are you on?

Comment: Or do you use any notebook extensions?

Comment: I am on Python 3.5.

Comment: These are my extensions `{
  "load_extensions": {
    "calico-spell-check": true,
    "calico-cell-tools": true,
    "usability/python-markdown/main": true,
    "calico-document-tools": true,
    "usability/spellchecker/main": true
  }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I traced the problem back to a CSS property `width:calc(275px)`:

```css
.dropdown-menu{
  max-height:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
  overflow-y:auto;
  width:calc(275px)
}
```

This is in my `extension.js` in `<install_dir>/anaconda/share/jupyter/nbextensions/jupyter-js-widgets`. Removing the `width` attribute solves the problem. I tried to look at the source at GitHub but couldn't figure out where this comes from.

Comment: How does one fix this without editing files in the installation directory? For the example I'm working on, I don't have admin access to that

Comment: Maybe there is a way to load a custom CSS-file from a location you can read from into a notebook that allows you to overwrite the CSS default settings?